# Using SelectRecords V2 and clsCCRecordSelect to save selected records to new table

Tags: ms-access, select, insert

I'm fairly new to Access and am having some difficulty utilizing the SelectRecords V2 example from the Bitsqueezer's database. The database tracks outreach efforts to various contacts.  Each contact person has their own record.

I have created the table (`tblContSelect`) from which the `frmMultiSelectCheckbox` form pulls records to select.  Once records are selected, I would like to click a Submit button and have copies of the records appended to another table, `tblContOutreach`.  I would like to keep the original records listed in the original table (`tblContSelect`), but clear the selections once the records are copied to the other table (`tblContOutreach`). In the table where the records are copied (`tblContOutreach`), it is possible for there to be multiple entries for the same contact.  When appended to the tables, records for the same contact should not be replaced or updated.  This table will show a history of outreach to each contact.

I am not sure where to start with coding the Submit button to copy the selected records into the other table.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

My apologies if this is not the right forum to ask about this.  I came across the SelectRecords V2 on SO and am trying to leverage it for a database I've inherited.  I have the form working with my data, but I can't figure out how to commit the selections to a new table on clicking a command button.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public objRecordSelect As clsCCRecordSelect

Private Sub cmdInvert_Click()
objRecordSelect.InvertAll
End Sub

Private Sub cmdRemoveAll_Click()
objRecordSelect.SetAllTo False
End Sub

Private Sub cmdSelectAll_Click()
objRecordSelect.SetAllTo True
End Sub

Private Sub cmdShowSelection_Click()
MsgBox objRecordSelect.SelectedIDs
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
Set objRecordSelect = New clsCCRecordSelect
objRecordSelect.InitSelect Me, Me.chkMultiSelect, "ID", "tblTest", , enmCCRecordSelectionMode_Multiple
End Sub

' Purpose     : Hilfsfunktion zum Aufruf in der Checkbox / im Optionbutton als ControlSource
'               Aufruf in der ControlSource der Checkbox / des OptionButtons muß so aussehen:
'               =fnGetSelection([ctlID])
'               Wobei "ctlID" der Name der Checkbox bzw. des Optionbuttons sein muß,
'               der zur Auswahl verwendet werden soll.
Private Function fnGetSelection(ID As Variant) As Boolean
On Error Resume Next
fnGetSelection = Me.objRecordSelect.GetSelection(ID)
End Function
```

The SelectRecords V2 example that I'm trying to implement can be found here: http://www.ccedv.de/downloads/start.php?lang=en

Comment: You can't assume that anyone here knows the example you use. At the moment your question is very unclear. Please describe the actual problem you have. And be aware that SO is not a code writing service. Please read [ask].

Comment: Write your code, and let us help you.